# How to add OTP expire time in flutter with firebase Phone Auth

Tags: firebase, flutter

```
 await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: mobile,
        timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
        verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
        verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
        codeSent: codeSent,
    );
```

i am using this snippet but the timeout mention in this is for autoOtpRetrievelTimeOut but i am looking for how i can add otp expiration time like after 60 seconds i want user to click resend OTP again

Answer (score 0):

```
 bool isTimeExpired = false;    

   Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 60), () {
      setState(() { //Replace setState with your state management
        // Enable Resend Option
        isTimeExpired = true;
      });
    
    });

await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: mobile,
        timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
        verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
        verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
        codeSent: codeSent,
   );

verificationCompleted(params)async{
   if(isTimeExpired){
     await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
     //your code
   }
}
```

Comment: i have already done this step .Basically i want that otp code should be expire after 60sec and dont allow user to login with the expire OTP . User will click resend OTP and he will recieve new OTP code and with in 60sec he can login with the new OTP-Code ! T
The Question is how i can add expire time for OTP-code is there any firebase function available??

Comment: i can still login with old otp this is the main problem otp time should be expire from firebase side !

Comment: You can call signOut from FirebaseAuth in verificationCompleted method and show the UI to resend the OTP and OTP expired !